# issues with opening files in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to open a file inFile.dat in c++. For some reason whenever I execute my program my else sequence triggers, saying that my program cannot open the file so it terminates. I have the file inFile.dat in the same folder as my program and .cpp. If anyone can spot a error I may have made, or maybe I am not doing something right that would be great. The programming platform I am using is dev c++ if that helps

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // declare variables to manipulate data
    string firstName, lastName;
    double testScore;
    char grade = ' ';
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // declare stream variables
    ifstream inFileData;
    ofstream outFileData;

    // Open input file
    inFileData.open("inFile.dat", ios::in);
    // open output file
    outFileData.open("outFile.dat", ios::out);

    if (outFileData.is_open() && inFileData.is_open()) {

        outFileData << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

        inFileData >> firstName >> lastName; // reading names
        inFileData >> testScore;            // reading test score

        while (inFileData) {
            sum = sum + testScore;      // update sum
            count++;                    // increment counter

            // deteremine the grade
            switch (static_cast<int> (testScore) / 100) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    grade = 'F';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    grade = 'D';
                    break;
                case 7:
                    grade = 'C';
                    break;
                case 8:
                    grade = 'B';
                    break;
                case 9:
                case 10:
                    grade = 'A';
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Invalid score."
                        << endl;
            } // end switch
            outFileData     << left << setw(12) << firstName
                            << setw(12) << lastName
                            << right << setw(4) << testScore
                            << setw(2) << grade
                            << endl;

            inFileData   >> firstName >> lastName;      // read the name
            inFileData   >> testScore;                 // read the test score
        }   // end while         
    } //  end if
    else
        cout << "Could not open file"
             << endl;

    outFileData << endl;

    if (count != 0)
        outFileData  << "Class Average: " 
                     << sum / count
                     << endl;
    else 
        outFileData  << "No data."
                     << endl;

        // closing files
    inFileData.close(); 
    outFileData.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The contents of inFile.dat is:

Steve Gill 89

Rita Johnson 91.5

Randy Brown 85.5

Seema Arora 76.5

Samir Mann 73

Samantha McCoy 88.5

Comment: "I have the file inFile.dat in the same folder as my program and .cpp."  - assuming you are using an IDE, your data files should probably be in the project directory.

Comment: Try and keep your code more minimal. If the file opening code is problematic, isolate that. The parsing here seems entirely irrelevant. Check that your current working directory is correct via [`getcwd`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd).

Comment: Are you sure your file exists?

Comment: Check whether the file is in the same directory as your program. Running your program with the file runs fine on my system..

Comment: @Charles Yeah, I am sure it exists.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, According to my instructor, as long as you have the file in the same directory as the program, the program should work. I have managed to do something exactly like this before, but for some reason this time I cant get it to work, and I'm not sure why

Comment: "According to my instructor, as long as you have the file in the same directory as the program, the program should work." - maybe your instructor can fix the problem then? If you are running things from an IDE, he is probably wrong.

Comment: @Rohan Kumar that's weird, the file is in the same area as the program, and I've even put a copy of it in every directory that I can imagine the program might be searching for that file. but it still doesn't seem to be able to find the file. Ill try recompiling on another computer and see if i have better luck then

Comment: @tadman, thanks for the advice, I tried to recreate a similar program in a different directory with different file names, but its still not workings. Could it be that my IDE is making the program search somewhere else? I keep my IDE and programs in separate directories, but when i run a similar program that I have made in the past it seems to work just fine

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, its possible. This is a problem from the book we are working with. I am going to email him if I cant find a solution after looking here.

Comment: When in doubt, specify the full path. Using relative paths is entirely dependent on how and where this command is launched.

Comment: Most likely the IDE has some way to specify what directory to change to when running the program.  Look for that setting.